Dynamically Show/Hide Custom Ribbon Tab
Currently I am developing a custom ribbon tab (using the Office CustomUI Editor) that is to show/hide when the user navigates to any page with "Roster" in its name. Below is my XML:
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="RibbonOnLoad">
<ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="customRosterTab" label="Roster Tools" getEnabled="IsRosterTabEnabled">
        <group id="rosterGroup" label="Roster Actions" />
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>

I am using the VB script in the ThisWorkbook module:
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Not ribbonUI Is Nothing Then
        ribbonUI.Invalidate ("customRosterTab") ' Forces the ribbon to refresh, calling IsRosterTabEnabled
    End If
End Sub

and the script below in a separate module:
Dim ribbonUI As IRibbonUI

' Initialize ribbon UI
Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set ribbonUI = ribbon
    MsgBox "Ribbon has loaded successfully!"
End Sub

' Callback function to enable/disable the tab based on sheet name
Function IsRosterTabEnabled(control As IRibbonControl) As Boolean
    ' Enable tab if the active sheet's name contains "Roster"
    IsRosterTabEnabled = InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Name, "Roster", vbTextCompare) > 0
End Function

Unfortunately, every time I change to any sheet containing "Roster" in its name, I get an "Object Required" error on this line "If Not ribbonUI Is Nothing Then" (because ribbonUI is empty).
I'm not sure how to fix this. Can anybody provide any insight?

Try Public ribbonUI As IRibbonUI, Microsoft documentation:

Declaring variables


Turns out, using the Tag attribute is ideal. Here's what I did:
In a standard module I put this
Option Explicit

Dim Rib As IRibbonUI
Dim MyTag As String

'Callback for customUI.onLoad
Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set Rib = ribbon
End Sub

Sub GetVisible(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef visible)
    If control.Tag Like MyTag Then
        visible = True
    Else
        visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Sub RefreshRibbon(Tag As String, Optional TabID As String)
    MyTag = Tag
    If Rib Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Error, restart your workbook"
    Else
        Rib.Invalidate
        If TabID <> "" Then Rib.ActivateTab TabID
    End If
End Sub

Then, in the ThisWorkbook module
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
        
        Select Case True
            Case Sh.Name Like "*Roster"
                Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="RosterTab", TabID:="tabRosterSheet")        
            Case Else
                Call RefreshRibbon(Tag:="")
        End Select

End Sub

And in my XML
<tab id="tabRosterSheet" label="Roster Sheet Tools" insertBeforeMso="TabInsert" tag="RosterTab" getVisible="GetVisible">

Works like a charm!

You could simplify things slightly by using Sub RefreshRibbon(Optional Tag As String = "", Optional TabID As String); then you can Call RefreshRibbon without any parameters in your Case Else and it will default to Tag="" if you don't specify it

There are two reasons to explain the error you receive:

As it was stated in the first comment, the object declaration is wrong and it cannot be accessed from ThisWorkbook code module. So, it must be declared as:

  Public ribbonUI As IRibbonUI


The ribbon object kept in a variable may be lost when you encounter a VBA error. For such a case, you should save/memorize its memory pointer. Please, copy the next code in the standard module where specific ribbon subs are kept:

Option Explicit

'This goes in the standard module top part, in the declarations area:
'To memorize the Ribbon object pointer! _____________________________________
#If VBA7 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal length As LongPtr)
#Else
        Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
#End If
'______________________________________________________________________

Public ribbonUI As IRibbonUI
Const strRib As String = "\MyRibb"

' Modify the initialization of ribbon UI in the next way:
Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Dim Path As String: Path = Environ("temp") & strRib
    Dim File As Integer: File = FreeFile
    Open Path For Output As #File
        Print #File, ObjPtr(ribbon) 'memorize IRibbonUI pointer
    Close #File

    Set ribbonUI = ribbon
    Debug.Print "Ribbon has loaded successfully!"    
End Sub

Sub getRibbon() 'reSet ribbonUI if it was lost (it's Nothing):
    Dim Path As String: Path = Environ("temp") & strRib
    Dim File As Integer: File = FreeFile
    Dim ribValue As String
    
    If ribbonUI Is Nothing Then
        Open Path For Input As #File
            Input #File, ribValue
        Close #File
        
        #If VBA7 Then
            CopyMemory ribbonUI, CLngPtr(ribValue), 8 'place in memory IRibbonUI object from its memorized pointer '64 bit
        #Else
            CopyMemory ribbonUI, CLng(ribValue), 4    'place in memory IRibbonUI object from its memorized pointer
        #End If
        Debug.Print "Ribbon object recuperated..."
    End If
End Sub

Keep in the above module all necessary functions, subs you are already using.
Now, modify your event code in the next way:
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If ribbonUI Is Nothing Then getRibbon 'ribbon object is recuperated if lost

    ribbonUI.Invalidate ("customRosterTab") ' Forces the ribbon to refresh, calling IsRosterTabEnabled
End Sub



Per the documentation, getEnabled is not a valid Attribute for the tab Element.
If you are trying to show/hide the tab in the ribbon, then you should use getVisible.
If you are trying to activate the tab in the ribbon, you should be calling the ActivateTab method (i.e. ribbonUI.ActivateTab "customRosterTab")

Furthermore, the get* Attributes do not use Functions with Return Values — they use Subroutines with ByRef variables that are assigned the value.
Instead of Function IsRosterTabEnabled(control As IRibbonControl) As Boolean or Function IsRosterTabVisible(control As IRibbonControl) As Boolean, you should be using Sub IsRosterTabEnabled(control AS IRibbonControl, ByRef enabled) or Sub IsRosterTabEnabled(control AS IRibbonControl, ByRef visible), like so:
' Callback function to show/hide the tab based on sheet name
Sub IsRosterTabVisible(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef visible)
    ' Show tab if the active sheet's name contains "Roster"
    visible = (InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Name, "Roster", vbTextCompare) > 0)
End Sub


Now, as FaneDuru mentioned, it is also possible to lose the Ribbon Pointer if your code breaks.  However, rather than creating a File on the machine, I would suggest using a Custom Workbook Property:
Option Explicit
Public ribbonUI As IRibbonUI

#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef destination As Any, ByRef source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
#Else
    Public Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef destination As Any, ByRef source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
Function GetRibbon(ByVal lRibbonPointer As LongPtr) As Object
#Else
Function GetRibbon(ByVal lRibbonPointer As Long) As Object
#End If
        Dim objRibbon As Object
        CopyMemory objRibbon, lRibbonPointer, LenB(lRibbonPointer)
        Set GetRibbon = objRibbon
        Set objRibbon = Nothing
End Function

' Initialize ribbon UI
Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set ribbonUI = ribbon
    SetCustomProperty "RibbonPointer", ObjPtr(ribbon), msoPropertyTypeNumber
    MsgBox "Ribbon has loaded successfully!"
End Sub

'Safe code to Set and Get CustomDocumentProperties
Public Sub SetCustomProperty(Name As String, Value As Variant, Optional PropertyType As MsoDocProperties)
    On Error GoTo CreateProperty
    ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties(Name) = Value
    Exit Sub
CreateProperty:
    'If PropertyType is undefined, attempt to work out the default between String, Integer, or Float
    Dim TrueType As MsoDocProperties
    If PropertyType > 0 Then
        TrueType = PropertyType
    Else
        Select Case TypeName(Value)
            Case "Integer", "Long"
                TrueType = msoPropertyTypeNumber
            Case "Boolean"
                TrueType = msoPropertyTypeBoolean
            Case "Date"
                TrueType = msoPropertyTypeDate
            Case "String"
                TrueType = msoPropertyTypeString
            Case "Double", "Float"
                TrueType = msoPropertyTypeFloat
            Case Else
                TrueType = msoPropertyTypeString
        End Select
    End If
    ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Add Name:=Name, LinkToContent:=False, Type:=TrueType, Value:=Value
    Resume
End Sub

Public Function GetCustomProperty(Name As String, Optional DefaultValue As Variant, Optional PropertyType As MsoDocProperties) As Variant
    On Error GoTo SetDefault
    GetCustomProperty = ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties(Name)
    Exit Function
SetDefault:
    SetCustomProperty Name, DefaultValue, PropertyType
    Resume
End Function

Then before doing anything with the Ribbon, such as trying ribbonUI.ActivateTab "customRosterTab", you can verify the ribbon like so: If ribbonUI Is Nothing Then Set ribbonUI = GetRibbon(GetCustomProperty("RibbonPointer"))
